# Facing issue while decrypting logstash encrypted data in ES

Tags: java, elasticsearch, encryption, logstash, logstash-filter

I'm encrypting some data using logstash cipher filter & store the encrypted data in elasticsearch. The code snippet used for the encryption is as follow:

```
filter {
cipher {
algorithm => "aes-256-cbc"
cipher_padding => 1
iv_random_length => 16
key => "<32_DIGITS_KEY>"
key_size => 32
mode => "encrypt"
source => "[message]"
target => "[message_enc]"
}
}
```

When I read the data from this elasticsearch index using java code & decrypt it then I'm getting same random unicode string before my actual data. Sample random string is "r��1�><��B9c�M****"

I didn't find anything in my code to resolve this issue.

Please help me in resolving this.

@gusto2

**Java code for decrypting the data is as follow:**

```
private static final String secretKey = "<32_DIGITS_KEY(SAME-AS-USED-IN-ENCRYPTION)>";
static String encrypt ;
//@PostConstruct
public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt , byte[] salt)
{
    try
    {
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(salt);

        SecretKeySpec speckKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, speckKey , ivspec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes());
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted ,byte[] salt) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(salt);

        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec , ivspec);
        //return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted)));
        byte[] original =  cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public  static void main (String args[]){
    byte[] IV = new byte[16];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    random.nextBytes(IV);
    final byte[] salt = IV;
    String strToEncrypt = "533032715323";
    encrypt = encrypt(strToEncrypt , salt);
    //encrypt = "w7oA8EdWmFNfBSUX1ZM0ixYU1Zep6tOnqz8b81X24n8=";
    System.out.println(encrypt);
    String decrpytStr = decrypt(encrypt , salt);
    System.out.println(decrpytStr);
    System.out.println(decrpytStr.equalsIgnoreCase(strToEncrypt));
}
```

Comment: Isn't that 'random' string the IV ? You may try to share your Java code.

Comment: @gusto2


Code mentioned.

Comment: My question is - where do you get the salt (IV) when decrypting the elasticsearch data? It should be first "iv_random_length" bytes. Then you should decrypt only rest of the input (not the whole)

Comment: The length of the salt is same as the vale of "iv_random_length" - 16. & the salt if 16 size random string.

Comment: Sample of our encrypted data is :

/FFTpP6XZqjfKR/+9mmSA9l4xTiW1MxeC3XDte+0z9w=

Comment: @gusto2

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting same random unicode string before my actual data

Having a look how the [cipher filter](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-cipher/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/cipher.rb) works, the output is in form of `Base64( iv + plaintext)`

> The length of the salt is same as the vale of "iv_random_length" - 16. & the salt if 16 size random string.

Using CBC mode the effect you have happens when IV is not correct.

The questions in comments were intended for you to realize what are you decrypting. When decrypting, the salt is not random. In this case it's the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext. So you should take the first 16 bytes, use them as IV and decrypt the rest.

```
   byte[] decodedCiphertext = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
   IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(decodedCiphertext, 0, 16);
   ...
   byte[] original =  cipher.doFinal(decodedCiphertext, 16, decodedCiphertext.length);
```

Comment: Thanks @gusto. Its working for decryption through java for logstash encrypted data.

But in some case we are encrypting the data using java for the same flow. It's not working in that case.

Please help.

Comment: _________________?